# How can I filter a set of data based on 4 conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, javascript-objects

I have data which is structured like so:

```
[
 {title: 'a', washday: 'true', cutday: 'false', colorday: 'true', deepconditionday: 'true'},
 {title: 'b', washday: 'false', cutday: 'true', colorday: 'false', deepconditionday: 'false'},
 {title: 'c', washday: 'true', cutday: 'false', colorday: 'true', deepconditionday: 'true'},
 {title: 'd', washday: 'false', cutday: 'false', colorday: 'false', deepconditionday: 'false'},
]
```

I also have states in my app for *cutday*, *colorday*, *deepconditionday* and *washday* where each one has a switch to toggle between booleans true and false.

How can I filter the above data according to which states are switched on? For example if only colorday is switch on, I want to show all items where colorday is 'true'. If both deepconditionday and cutday are switched on, I want to show all items where both cutday and deepconditionday are 'true'.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are your "boolean" values stored as strings? *"I also have states"*: can you add code so we see how those states are defined?

Comment: You have to show what you have tried, otherwise we don't know what you're having trouble with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

maybe like so:

```
  let titleFilter = "a";
  let washdayFilter = true;
  let cutdayFilter = true;

  let filteredData = data.filter(
    (datapoint) =>
      datapoint.title == titleFilter &&
      datapoint.washday == washdayFilter.toString() &&
      datapoint.cutday == cutdayFilter.toString()
  );
```

Comment: `'true' != true`

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
         {title: 'a', washday: 'true', cutday: 'false', colorday: 'true', deepconditionday: 'true'},
         {title: 'b', washday: 'false', cutday: 'true', colorday: 'false', deepconditionday: 'false'},
         {title: 'c', washday: 'true', cutday: 'false', colorday: 'true', deepconditionday: 'true'},
         {title: 'd', washday: 'false', cutday: 'false', colorday: 'false', deepconditionday: 'false'}
        ]
    
const filterData = (data, isWashDay, isCutDay, isColorDay, isDeepConditionDay)=>{
    return data.filter((item)=>{
         (isWashDay === 'any' | isWashDay ==== item.washday) &&
              (isCutDay === 'any' | isCutDay ==== item.cutday) &&
              (isColorDay === 'any' | isColorDay ==== item.colorday) &&
              (isDeepConditionDay === 'any' | isDeepConditionDay ==== item.deepconditionday) 
     })
}
console.log(filterData(data, 'true', 'any', 'any', 'any'))
```

More info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Do take note that you've used 'true' and 'false' as strings, and not booleans, so I did the same.
You should use a boolean and change the code accordingly though
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: Why `any`? OP never said anything about a magic string `any`

Comment: added because OP said they want to filter maybe just for one prop
>For example if only colorday is switch on, I want to show all items where colorday is 'true'. 
this way you can specify true, false or any.

Comment: That's not very safe, it'd be more intuitive to pass an object with the keys you want to filter by instead of relying on magic strings

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented example use ReactJS and MaterialUI. Just use states for switchs and filter by states. Link demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-176e3?file=/demo.js

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";

export default function DisableElevation() {
    const [isWashday, setIsWashday] = useState(false);
    const [isCutday, setIsCutday] = useState(false);
    const [isColorday, setIsColorday] = useState(false);
    const [isDeepconditionday, setIsDeepconditionday] = useState(false);

    const data = [
        {title: 'a', washday: true, cutday: false, colorday: true, deepconditionday: true},
        {title: 'b', washday: false, cutday: true, colorday: false, deepconditionday: false},
        {title: 'c', washday: true, cutday: false, colorday: true, deepconditionday: true},
        {title: 'd', washday: false, cutday: false, colorday: false, deepconditionday: false},
    ];


    const handleChange = (event) => {
        switch (event.target.name) {
            case 'isWashday':
                setIsWashday(event.target.checked);
                break;
            case 'isCutday':
                setIsCutday(event.target.checked);
                break;
            case 'isColorday':
                setIsColorday(event.target.checked);
                break;
            case 'isDeepconditionday':
                setIsDeepconditionday(event.target.checked);
                break;

            default:
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>

            <div> {data.filter(datum => (!isWashday || datum.washday) && (!isCutday || datum.cutday) && (!isColorday || datum.colorday) && (!isDeepconditionday || datum.deepconditionday)).map(r => r.title + " ")} </div>
            <div>
                <span>isWashday</span>
                <Switch
                    checked={isWashday}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="isWashday"
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>isCutday</span>
                <Switch
                    checked={isCutday}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="isCutday"
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>isColorday</span>
                <Switch
                    checked={isColorday}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="isColorday"
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>isDeepconditionday</span>
                <Switch
                    checked={isDeepconditionday}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="isDeepconditionday"
                    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: if i choose washday and cutday it should be a,b,c because cutday is true on title b. No output on your demo if i switch on the washday and cutday

Comment: as i know, both conditons must true

Comment: Follow description: If both deepconditionday and cutday are switched on, I want to show all items where both cutday and deepconditionday are 'true'.

Comment: oh sorry my comprehension mistake. You are correct. Thanks